# WCF with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I want to use EF behind my WCF service to fetch data and display it to the client. I need the following suggestions:

1. Do I need to have the same interface for all the views (e.g. students, teachers etc.) or do I need to have a different interface and service for every table (or view)
2. Do I need to generate the database calls within my service (`.svc`) or some other architecture is preferred?

   ```
   public Student[] GetAllStudents()
   {
      //database generation code here
   }
   ```
3. How can I use EF code-first approach to generate database. I know that for an MVC app, you need to set the initializer in `Global.asax` or in `web.config` but I am not sure how it's called in this case. My model looks like this:

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class Student
   {
       [DataMember]
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string Type { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. No; you can, does make things cleaner; 2. Hmm maybe OData may help here? 3. Sounds like you might benefit from a tutorial article rather than something on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really should do is break up your system in to more separate layers. Instead of having a WCF call that directly queries the database, create a "buisness logic" layer that translates the information that the WCF call provides you to what the EF call needs to know. This is called a [N-Tier application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384398.aspx)

```
public class SchoolAPI : ISchoolAPI
{
    private DataAccessLayer _dal = new DataAccessLayer();

    public Student[] GetAllStudents()
    {
        return _dal.GetStudents(null, null);
    }

    public Student[] GetAllScienceStudents()
    {
        return _dal.GetStudents(null, DataAccessLayer.ScienceStudentType);
    }
}

private class DataAccessLayer
{
    public static readonly ScienceStudentType = //...

    public Student[] GetStudents(string subject, string type)
    {
        using(var ctx = new SchoolContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Student> studentQuery = ctx.Students;

            if(subject != null)
                studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(s=>s.Subject == subject);

            if(type != null)
                studentQuery = studentQuery.Where(s=>s.Type == type);

            return studentQuery.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The caller of the WCF call does not need to know what the string `ScienceStudentType` is, all it cares about is that it gets the science students. By seperating the business logic from the database call the caller of your service no longer needs to know.

For EF it will initialize on the first time the framework goes out to "touch" the database and detects that it is not there if it is set up to do so. This is done in the constructor of `SchoolContext` but is getting a little too broad for this answer. I recommend finding a tutorial on EF and get it working in a simple test enviorment without WCF (maybe a simple console app that just calls `GetStudents(`) then move in in to a WCF environment.

Comment: Does it mean: 1) to create an MVC based solution first, 
2) generate the database and if all works well, 
3) add a WCF application project in the solution, 
4) Call the MVC based DAL layer by adding its reference to the WCF project 
5) Remove the Controllers and Views as they are not required. 

Please correct me where required

Comment: Use 3 projects, 1) A DAL dll that is totally independent of what uses it. 2) A "sandbox project" to get it up and running, including the project from #1 as a refrence. This could be a console app, a MVC web app, or anything, it  is only temporary to act as your scaffolding until you get your kinks worked out with EF. 3) Your WCF Project that also uses the DLL from #1.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Chamberlain
One last advice. 
1) Can I inherit my DAL from the same interface i.e. ISchool which I am using for my WCF service?
2) What if I have to define multiple methods in my WebService, like Student's methods from IStudent, Teacher's methods from ITeacher?
Thanks in advance.